# Eclipse plugin from existing jar

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar, osgi

Using the tutorial, I created a eclipse plugin from existing jar. Its properly created and am able to see the **class files** with **META-INF/SERVICES** files available in jar (unZIPPED the jar).

Now I need to update one of the property file under META-INF/SERVICES of extracted jar files and add a new test.java file under one of the package, No doubt am able to do that.

But my aim is to build the project so that my test.java file will be converted as test.class,

Is there a way to do this.

Comment: Write an ANT file for doing the same.

Comment: You can try an export (`right click on project > Export...`) by selecting what fits your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expot plugin option to export your plugin, from [Plug-in Export](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fexport_wizards%2Fexport_plugins.htm)

The export wizard is available under:

**`File > Export... > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments`** .

See the liked doc for more details.